# How do i get the publish profile name in an msbuild task?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, msbuild-task

I have pre-build and post-build tasks and I reference the configuration with: `$(ConfigurationName)`

What is the variable for the publish profile name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would believe the msbuild property is `$(PublishProfile)`.